# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: solr: Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, windows, apache, solr, xampp

I'm getting the below warning while adding the solr-client extinctions.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: solr: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
```

can any one Please hep me out in this ?

Comment: php and module version mismatch

Comment: @bansi what can i do in this case any idea ?
means do i need to update php or solr ?

Comment: you are using module compiled for PHP 5.6.0 on your PHP version is 5.5.6. you have 2 options. upgrade PHP or get module compiled for your php version. If you have source code of the module, re-compile with your PHP version.

Comment: @bansi it Works

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Warning: PHP Startup: solr: Unable to initialize module**

1:Check extension_dir directive in php.ini. It should point to folder with 5.2 modules.

2:This is because PHP extensions are developped in C, and are "close" to the internals of PHP -- which means that, if the APIs of those internals change, the extension must be re-compiled, to use the new versions.

And, between PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3, for what I remember, there have been some modifications in the internal data-structures used by the PHP engine -- which means extensions must be re-compiled, in order to match that new version of those data-structures.

How to update your PHP extensions will depend on which system you are using.

If you are on windows, you can find the .dll for some extensions here : http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ 
For more informations about the different versions, you can take a look at what's said on the left-sidebar of windows.php.net.

If you are on Linux, you must either :

Check what your distribution provides
Or use the pecl command, to re-download the sources of the extensions in question, and re-compile them.

Comment: @ Naveen Gupta All in one r u bro when you start work in php..?